# Al unir tres tablas mysql, un registro aparece duplicado

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Como podrán ver, el problema es que los géneros aparecen repetidos, aunque el numero de veces que se repite es la correcta
[image: Este es la consulta y resultado]

[image: las tablas que estoy usando]

**Nota: ya resolvi el problema, el group by era el que estaba interfiriendo**

```
SELECT serie_db.nombre,rating,GROUP_CONCAT(genero.nombre) FROM serie_db left join serie_db_generos on serie_db_generos.serie_db_id = serie_db.id left join genero on serie_db_generos.genero_id = genero.id group by serie_db_generos.serie_db_id
```

Comment: sería mejor si tu consulta la pones como texto.

Comment: apenas hoy me uní al foro, gracias por la sugerencia :D

Comment: *aunque el numero de veces que se repite es la correcta*: entonces, ¿el resultado es correcto o no? Jesus te dejó una buena respuesta para eliminar las repeticiones. Pero, tal vez es cuestión de entender mejor tus los datos y ver si es que se requiere otro tipo de modificación. Pero por ahora no has explicado los datos de tus diferentes tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta agregar `DISTINCT` dentro del `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genero.nombre)
```

Una representacion rapida en FIDDLE de lo que quieres lograr: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b67c2/2/0

**Nota: Agrupa por el id o nombre de la serie para lograr el efecto deseado**

Comment: pero ahora los géneros no aparecen concatenados

Comment: no, de hecho, eso no es lo correcto, ya que cada registro puede tener el mismo genero que otro

Comment: Creo que tu 'group by genero.id' es el que esta interfiriendo con la agrupacion y deberias estar agrupando por serie_db.id o serie_db.nombre

Comment: ese era el problema! gracias!